# Xcode preferences, Behaviors section, "speak announcement using" language?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In Xcode, under *Preferences* (command+comma), in the *Behaviors* section, there is an option to "Speak announcement using". This option has a pull down list of women's names. I have tried several women's names, and they all seem to be speaking a (different?) foreign language.

[image]

Which woman's name corresponds to English? Or better yet, what is the corresponding language for each name? There are a lot of names for me to sift through.

[image]

I'm on macOS Sierra if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up here to save people some time, the `en_US` voices from `say -v ?` are:

- masculine: Alex, Fred
- feminine: Samantha, Victoria

Fred and Victoria have very robotic voices so I would recommend choosing either Alex or Samantha.

Answer (score 2):

You can type: `say -v ?` in terminal to see the list ov all voices and their languages

Like you've said: Samantha is reading using en_US.

Comment: Just notice that `say -v ?` output is not the same as the options on Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Good Grief! I stumbled upon the right name while writing this question: **Samantha**.

The reasons I wrote this question was because I was tired of trying out different names looking for English, and I was not being disciplined in changing the name after each build, and I was forgetting my place from my progress yesterday.

In the composing of this question, I chose my next name to test: "Samantha" and sure enough on my next build I heard English. I guess I gave up too early, but it was looking hopeless for a while.

Still, it would be nice if there was a list of corresponding languages to names.